# Show that if $a = a^{-1}$ then $a=1$ or $a=-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is as the title states, with the additional information that $a\in A$ where $A$ is a field, and $a$ is non-zero.

I don't get very far, simply that
$a^{-1} = a \iff a\cdot a = 1$. But from here I don't know what to do.

Comment: @don-thousand This is perfectly well defined: $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has $a^2 = 1$ if and only if $(a-1)(a+1) = 0$. In a field, this implies $a - 1 = 0$ or $a + 1 = 0$.